# не выводится ошибка валидации для reCaptcha thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, recaptcha

```
    <div class="'ui form error">
        <div th:class="field">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeB7t*************f__BOB55heEdAWqT"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="ui error message" th:if="${captchaError} ">
            <div class="header">Ошибка!</div>
            <p th:text="${captchaError}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

В остальных полях работает, например:

```
    <div class="field">
        <label>Имя пользователя</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
    </div>
    <div class="ui form error">
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px" class="ui error message" th:if="${usernameError}" >
            <div class="header">Ошибка!</div>
            <p th:text="${usernameError}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

В модели captchaError присутствует, если вывести без th:if th:text=${captchaError} нормально выводится.

Comment: Что в логе? Есть сомнение что `captchaError` может быть `null`. Условие в этом случае должно быть как-то так ... `th:if="${not #strings.isEmpty(captchaError)}"`

Comment: captchaError точно не null, в модели есть и при выводе без условия выводится в шаблоне